# Bardic performance in battle requires a check if the bard is damaged?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, class, bard

Rules for barding performance states that:

> Starting a bardic performance is a standard action, but it can be
>   maintained each round as a free action. A bardic performance cannot be
>   disrupted, but it ends immediately if the bard is killed, paralyzed,
>   stunned, knocked unconscious, or otherwise prevented from taking a
>   free action to maintain it each round.

Question: Let`s say bard engaged into battle, while using "Bardic performance". If he recieves damage, should player roll some check (like concentration for spellcasters)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**

> A bardic performance cannot be disrupted

Damage does not prevent the bard from taking the free action needed to maintain the bardic performance. Furthermore, the quoted text above tells us that ordinary concerns - like loud noises, distractions, damage, or the succubi you're fighting suddenly professing their undying love for you - don't disrupt the performance whatsoever. Only something sufficient to prevent the bard from taking free actions can stop the performance against the bard's will.